# Access second WIFI card with Python

Tags: python, wifi

I have a device that can transmit a WIFI signal. I would like to receive data from the device on one WIFI board and use the other board for the Internet. I am using Windows. Is something like this this possible with Python?

```
import some_WIFI_package as wifi

#connect to second wifi board
SSID = "myssid"
password = "mypassword"    
wifi.connect(SSID, password)


"""
sniff data
"""
```